# Ways in which low rep users can contribute in the Election

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-election

Currently I am a low-rep user so I can't vote in the elections till I reach 150.
But I would like to contribute in this Election.

**What options are open for me?**

(I think posting questions in that QA might be helpful so I [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121713) too)

Comment: As they used to say, *lurk moar*. 150 rep are the minimal guarantee you know how the community works enough to vote for whom will have the privileges and power to enforce its will. *(Re: Rohit Jain's answer, your account is only five months old on this site. I would allow at least one year before you start voting for moderators -- it's like voting for the mayor of a town you just settled in.)*

Comment: Answer questions, get rep, vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be great to have you contribute in the elections in some way. Since election ends in another 15 days, you've enough time to be eligible for voting. There are few options:

- Ask good questions.
- Answer questions with good answers.

Every upvote on answer gets you 10 points, and every answer accepted gets you another 15 points. So, you will quickly reach the threshold value with that. But refrain from asking bad questions (which can be easily answered by doing a simple google search), because that will only get you downvotes, which you don't want.